# Total parallax website moves when opening fancybox2

Tags: jquery, fancybox, parallax

I created a parallax website as an example. It works great, except that I use fancybox2 to pop-up portfolio items. The site seems to move in its totality when opening a `fancybox`.

The `margin` and `padding` attributes of `body` are set to `0`. All backgrounds are fixed. It seems it has something to do with the `scrollbar` and the `fancybox-lock` which appears when opening `fancybox`. When I set the `fancybox` like this the background is fixed like it should be:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
      autoSize: false,
      width: 780,
      helpers : { overlay : { locked : false } }  
    });
```

The problem is that now I can scroll the background. So setting `locked` to `true` is good but causes the scrollbar to be disabled and move all my backgrounds.

Is there a way to fix this?

This is my [portfolio website](http://www.jeroenbalk.nl).

Comment: Try the latest update that you can download from here https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/archive/master.zip then try setting the `locked` value to `true`

Comment: I already got the 2.1.5 version so using that files won't change a thing..

Comment: the version from the github link is v2.1.5 indeed **BUT** it contains fixes that the version from the website http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license doesn't ... did you tried it at least?

Answer (score 0):

On jquery.fancybox.css (line 167, version of October 2013), comment this class:

> .fancybox-lock {
>       overflow: hidden !important;
>       width: auto; }

Then you got

> /* DISABLING AUTO SCROLL
>   .fancybox-lock {
>       overflow: hidden !important;
>       width: auto; }
>   */

Hope it will solve your problem!

Cheers.